# How can we get positive confirmation that a file *does not* exist in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

The documentation for fileExistsAtPath reads:

> returns YES if a file at the specified path exists, or NO if the file
>   does not exist or its existence could not be determined.

This seems to prevent us using this method to get a positive determination of the *absence* of a file. If we get a NO back, it *might* mean the file doesn't exist, but it also *might* mean that the operating system couldn't tell. Therefore, what is the best way to assure ourselves that a file is absent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have not done anything strange with the attributes of the file or the file's folders, and as long as you are only working within your app's sandbox, then using `fileExistsAtPath` will give you the answer you need.

The "could not be determined" case only comes up when trying to access files outside of your app's sandbox or if you start messing with the attributes of folders inside your app's sandbox such as removing the ability to read or execute a folder.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how you know this to be true? Is there documentation about it somewhere?

Comment: It's part working with Unix style operating systems for 30 years and part writing file-intensive iOS apps since the App Store opened. I don't know if there is any specific documentation that states anything similar.

Answer (score 4):

Apple recommends against relying on the fileExistAtPath: method. It's often better to just try to open a file and deal with the error if the file does not exist.

> NSFileManager Class Reference
>
> Note: Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the file system or a particular file on the file system is not recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior or race conditions. It's far better to attempt an operation (such as loading a file or creating a directory), check for errors, and handle those errors gracefully than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation will succeed. For more information on file system race conditions, see “Race Conditions and Secure File Operations” in Secure Coding Guide.
> From the secure coding guide.

And from the ["Secure Coding Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002415):

> To prevent this, programs often check to make sure a temporary file with a specific name does not already exist in the target directory. If such a file exists, the application deletes it or chooses a new name for the temporary file to avoid conflict. If the file does not exist, the application opens the file for writing, because the system routine that opens a file for writing automatically creates a new file if none exists.
>
> An attacker, by continuously running a program that creates a new temporary file with the appropriate name, can (with a little persistence and some luck) create the file in the gap between when the application checked to make sure the temporary file didn’t exist and when it opens it for writing. The application then opens the attacker’s file and writes to it (remember, the system routine opens an existing file if there is one, and creates a new file only if there is no existing file).
>
> The attacker’s file might have different access permissions than the application’s temporary file, so the attacker can then read the contents. Alternatively, the attacker might have the file already open. The attacker could replace the file with a hard link or symbolic link to some other file (either one owned by the attacker or an existing system file). For example, the attacker could replace the file with a symbolic link to the system password file, so that after the attack, the system passwords have been corrupted to the point that no one, including the system administrator, can log in.